# I get this error: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in my database table that is of type Number(5,3). I need to be able to insert data or update data to this column. I am currently using a form field that lets users input whatever number they want. This field is the one used when inserting or updating data into this column of type Number(5,3). When testing I enter any number and get this error: **ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column**

I am aware the data type NUMBER(5,3) means 5 is precision (total number of digits) and the 3 means scale (number of digits to the right of decimal point). For example: 52.904

Is there a function in oracle to format any number into a number of this type: NUMBER(5,3)?

Again I would like for the user to input any number on the field and be able to process that number as NUMBER(5,3) to insert or update into my table.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense. Is there a good reason for the column to be constrained as it is? If there is a good reason, then users shouldn't be allowed to enter "any number" - if they enter a number like 3500 they should get an error message. Otherwise you can modify the column to accept a greater range of numbers (for example, change it to number(10,3) if you want to allow up to seven digits in the integer part).

Comment: @mathguy I cannot change the data type of the column.  This is for a legacy app and I already asked about this and had no permission.

Comment: OK, but then whoever doesn't give you permission should understand that a number like 100 cannot be stored in that column. Period. There is no workaround, no exception, etc. The best you can do is to have an error message back to users when they try to enter values that don't fit in `number(5, 3)`. Note that if their numbers have too many decimals, Oracle will round the value to three decimal places - that is not the problem. The problem is the integer part having three or more digits.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:
select cast (512.33333333 as number(5,2)) from dual;